# Mongoose removing a specific comment in an array that is attached to User

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

--NodeJS, Mongoose, MongoDB, ExpressJS, EJS--

My website is, there is a login user, where they can submit "name" and "image" of what they want, then the author and other people can comment on that picture. On per each image, i added a function where i count the comments using the .length function which is counting the comments on the picture and projects the number of comments to my ejs file.

here is my schema:

```
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Loginuser"
        },
            username: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Loginuser"
        },
        username: String
    },
    text: String,
    date: String
});

var loginSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String
});


var TestData = mongoose.model("User", testSchema);
var Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
var LoginUser = mongoose.model("Loginuser", loginSchema);
```

I have a function that deletes a comment on User,

```
app.delete("/index/:id/comments/:comment_id", function(req, res){
    Comment.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id, function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/index/");
        } else {
            console.log("Comment successfully deleted!");
            res.redirect("back");
        }
    });
});
```

Here's some sample data from my mongoDB
**commentSchema**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d316e506d8e9186c168a49"), 
  "text" : "hey baby! why cry?", "
__v" : 0, 
  "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("57d148acd0f11325b0dcd3e6"), 
  "username" :
  "nagy" }, 
  "date" : "9/10/2016 , 8:07 AM" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d316f706d8e9186c168a4a"), 
  "text" : "don't you cry baby!",
"__v" : 0, 
  "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("57d095d727e6b619383a39d0"), 
  "username": "doge" }, 
  "date" : "9/10/2016 , 8:07 AM" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d3170306d8e9186c168a4b"), 
  "text" : "wow so cute!!!!!!", "_
_v" : 0, 
 "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("57d095d727e6b619383a39d0"), 
 "username" : "doge" }, "date" : "9/10/2016 , 8:07 AM" }
```

and here's my data on **testSchema**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d316c506d8e9186c168a47"), 
      "name" : "Baby crying", 
      "image": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/d0/bb/ed/d0bbed614353534df9a3be0abe
    5f1d78.jpg", 
       "comments" : [ ObjectId("57d316e506d8e9186c168a49"), ObjectId("57d3
    16f706d8e9186c168a4a") ], "author" : { "id" : ObjectId("57d095d727e6b619383a39d0
    "), "username" : "doge" }, "__v" : 2 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d316dc06d8e9186c168a48"), 
  "name" : "Maria?! OZawa?!", 
  "image" : "https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/1092/1092126-bigthumb
nail.jpg", 
  "comments" : [ ObjectId("57d3170306d8e9186c168a4b") ], "author" : { "
id" : ObjectId("57d148acd0f11325b0dcd3e6"), "username" : "nagy" }, "__v" : 1 }
```

It is working fine, it's deleting the comment. The problem here is, it is deleting only on the "Comment" model.

I want to delete that same comment also on "TestData" model, because everytime i delete a comment, the count of comments remains the same.

So basically i want to delete that specific comment on both models.

I tried using this approach:

```
app.delete("/index/:id/comments/:comment_id", function(req, res){
        TestData.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id)function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/index");
        } else {
            res.redirect("back");
        }
    });
});
```

but it isn't working.

Can you help me on what specific query should i use?

Comment: `req.params.comment_id` is id of comments model right? You should use different id for testData to delete. Can you also add some sample db data also in your question?

Comment: yes, .comment_id is for the id on my "Comment" model, here is some sample data that i gathered on mongodb...This for my testSchema `> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d29ac85643520a946b1ccc"), "name" : "John", "image" : "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1501070030/John_2011_1_500x500.png", "comments"
 : [ ObjectId("57d29acf5643520a946b1ccd"), ObjectId("57d2a2d684b1b505188e2807"),
 ObjectId("57d2a3c43cf15600b436f190"), ObjectId("57d2a42e3cf15600b436f191") ], "
author" : { "id" : ObjectId("57d0950d3fd4142528a054e1"), "username" : "johnfrades" }, "__v" : 4 }`

Comment: and here is for my commentSchema  `> db.comments.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d0871c892abb230ca5a728"), "name" : "John F", "text" : "how
 old are you man", "date" : "9/8/2016 , 9:28 AM", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d092c0d32983243c1c0faf"), "name" : "Mike", "text" : "hey j
ohn, what gel did you use?", "date" : "9/8/2016 , 10:20 AM", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d09d94db073f272816ee12"), "text" : "you looked like a crim
inal bruh!", "date" : "9/8/2016 , 11:06 AM", "__v" : 0 }`   Thank you!

Comment: Please add it in your question. It is not readable in the comments.

Comment: you have any common field between these two database? Or do you have _id of testSchema while deleting?

Comment: the common field between the database is the comments i think? and also the username of the commenter.  The ObjectID of comment on "TestData" model is the same on ObjectID on "Comment" model.. sorry bro, these are my old comments thats been deleted. it still there, wait i'll erase all my database 1st and reattach again the data here

Comment: there bro, i deleted my database because it contains deleted comments... this is a new one... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

```
  TestData.update(
             {}, 
             {$pull: {comments: req.params.comment_id}},  
             { multi: true },
             function(err, data){
                  console.log(err, data);
             });
```

Hope this will help you.